# How to analyse large Networks/Graphs with limited amount of RAM

Tags: networking, graph, analysis, cytoscape.js, large-data

For a current project, I need to analyse a large Protein-Protein-Interaction Network given to me in an >300mb .csv file. 
The Graph will have way over 5 Million edges and tens of thousands of nodes.

I allready tried using Cytoscape and Gephi to load and analyse my Data, but both seem to not be capable of handling networks of this size. 
While Cytoscape crashes seconds after trying to load the file, Gephi manages to load ~50% until it runs out of memory. (Yes, I set -Xmx to max.)

Note, my PC has 8GB of RAM.

At this point, I'm starting to question myself: Is it even possible to analyse networks of this size with common Network-Analysis Software, or am I forced to write and tweak my own algorithms? Or is there Software available you guys know about?

For now, I don't necessarily need Graph visualisation, just simple Centrality measurements etc.

I really hope my question isn't too unspecific.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Both Cytoscape.js and Cytoscape desktop (Java) support headless mode.

You can use Cytoscape.js directly in Node.js, with direct access to its API.  Just `require('cytoscape')` and you're good to go.  Using Cytoscape.js headlessly in Node.js is much less expensive w.r.t. CPU usage and RAM, as compared to visualising.  Cytoscape.js supports lots of types of centrality calculations.  It's just one API call to calculate the values, so it would be easy to try out even just in the Node.js REPL (and you could write out a JSON file).

You can communicate with Cytoscape desktop headlessly via CyRest -- i.e. HTTP/REST requests.  This means you can do your analysis in any language, but everything you do will be async and require constant serialisation and deserialisation.  I think you could alternatively write an app for Cytoscape desktop, as long as it's all headless.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer @maxkfranz.

While searching for a solution, I found [SNAP]
(http://snap.stanford.edu/). It's a C++/Python library developed to analyse huge graphs and networks with up to Billions of Nodes and Edges. It comes with several packages to analyse the Networks properties and provides easy accessible datastructures. 
You can also create plots using [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) or [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/). 


It perfectly fits my needs, as I need to apply simple centrality analysis on a huge network without the need of direct visualization.

Comment: However, I plan to analyse Subnetworks with Cytoscape, so I'm happy that Cytoscape supports headless mode!

Comment: @reg_ist Great that some OSS works for you!  Keep the Cytoscape projects in mind in future projects, because they have a lot of features specifically designed for bio.